# Как вытащить информацию с устройства

Tags: visual-c++, javascript

В определенной сети есть несколько устройст которые имеют веб интерфейс, в нем отображается некий параметр на каждром устройсте (числовой значение уровня), доступ к ним по ip адресу. Вопрос в следующем, можно ли получить этот параметр что бы мониторить постоянно? Так как довольно долго и неудобно каждое устройство проверять хочется в одном окне собрать значения со всех устройств. И если можно такое сделать то на каком языке? К примеру на с++?

Comment: Можно и на C++. Но на таких языках, как Python, tcl/tk и пр. -- легче и быстрее.

Comment: парсить вебморду? хм, а не поддерживают ли эти устройства snmp запросы? написать аггрегатор... так будет проще и православнее...

Comment: Поддерживает, но там все не явно отображено, я так понимаю зашифровал производитель.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать страничку с JQuery и делать AJAX запросы к веб-интерфейсам устройств. Там же из возвращенного HTML кода можно с помощью регулярных выражений вытащить значения интересующих параметров.

Мне кажется, что это будет проще, чем С++. Задача ведь только посмотреть глазами, правильно?

Comment: посути да, еще бы их хранить какоето время к примеру неделю. А можно где то почитать поподробнее про "страничку с JQuery и делать AJAX запросы"

Comment: Можно посмотреть здесь http://jquery-docs.ru/ajax/jquery-ajax/
Про хранить сложнее, надо думать ещё :)

Comment: ну постоянная запись не нужна а вот раз в часа 2 считывать показатели и записывать в файлик или еще куда-нибудь было бы хорошо

Comment: На \*nix я бы посоветовал wget и скрипт над ним.

Comment: А не секрет, что за устройства? Может быть у них есть что-то более удобное для программного чтения, чем HTML'ка?

Comment: тв приемники оптические. интересует уровень оптического сигнала

Comment: @tabby_cat а оно будет работать?

Answer (score 0):

всё реализуемо на HTML5/jQuery и хранилище (WebStorage)
предвидя вопрос, что это и как, рекоммендую посмотреть презентацию [тут](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#web-storage)

но работать будет только на баузерах, поддерживающий стандарт HTML5, т.е. IE идёт лесом.

плюс: доступ с мобильных устройств (андроид, айфон, айпад и тд)

Comment: @Anri, Вы уверены, что автору интересны браузеры? 

В вопросе-то говорится о C++ (видимо речь о какой-то своей системе мониторинга).